# adding inputs to html form, using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have an html form that I would like to add inputs fields to using javascript. Originally I had the input fields by themselves underneath the 'body', and the following was able to add the fields:

```
            // Create number input field
            var phoneInput = document.createElement("INPUT");
            phoneInput.id = "phone" + instance;
            phoneInput.name = "phone" + instance;
            phoneInput.type = "text";

            // Insert that stuff
            document.body.insertBefore(document.createElement("BR"), element);
            document.body.insertBefore(phoneLabel, element);
            document.body.insertBefore(phoneInput, element);
```

I then added a 'form' element around the original inputs in the html file.

```
    <body>
    <form action=searchform.php method=GET>
        <LABEL for="phone1">Cell #: </LABEL>
        <input id="phone1" type="text" name="phone1">
        <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="New text box" onclick="newTextBox(this);" />
    </form>
    </body>
```

Now the button doesn't add new text boxes. Have I structured this incorrectly?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are appending the elements to the body, which means that `insertBefore` cannot find `element` (because it's in the `<form>`, not the `<body>`), so it never gets inserted.

A quick way to fix this would be to use `document.body.firstChild.insertBefore`. However, if the form is no longer the first element in the `body`, this will no longer work.

A cleaner, better way would be to give your form an ID (e.g. `<form id="myform">`), and then access the form using: `document.getElementById("myform").insertBefore`. Then you can place your form anywhere, and it will still be accessible using the ID.

Comment: hmmm, incase the body had a lot more children, is there a way I could label the form with an id, and then have the insertBefore point to that? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Gve the form an id

```
<form id="myForm" action="searchform.php" method="GET">
```

Create the JavaScript elements just as you used to, then you can just add the elements like so:

```
var f = document.getElementById('myForm');
f.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
f.appendChild(phoneLabel);
f.appendChild(phoneInput);
```

(`insertbefore` would work on `f` as well, although I think this is more readable.)

Answer (score 2):

Easiest would be to use jQuery. Add an ID to your form, for easier reference:

```
<form id="myform" action="action" method="GET">
  <input type="hidden" name="a" value="1"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="b" value="2"/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#myform").append('<input type="hidden" name="c" value="3"/>');
</script>
```

You can later change the value of your new input, by easily referring to it:

```
$("#myform input[name='c']").val(7);
```